# convert ISO date time string into a Date() object

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Using Javascript how do I convert ISO string 2013-08-10T12:10:15.474Z into a date ()object. do not use moment

I want to end up with  HH MM SS    MM DD YYYY

date.parse converts the string into milliseconds since 1/1/70  That is not what I want.

Comment: What happened when you tried `new Date('2013-08-10T12:10:15.474Z')`? Or `Date.parse()`?

Comment: What about using `Date.parse('2013-08-10T12:10:15.474Z')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change ISO Date String to Date Object - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012854/change-iso-date-string-to-date-object-javascript)

Comment: Date.parse() does not return a date object...

Comment: Regarding your edit, and the desired output format, if you just need a string in a different format and not a `Date()` object the easiest way is to do it all as string manipulation: a one-liner with the string `.replace()` method and a regex.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `new Date('2013-08-10T12:10:15.474Z')` or `Date.parse('2013-08-10T12:10:15.474Z')`.