# How to convert 2021-04-18T00:00:00Z to utc 8+

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm new to this and I'm really confuse bout this format of date. Can Anyone tell me what kind of format is this(2021-04-18T00:00:00Z) how to convert it to utc 8+

Im developing a message extension for microsoft teams app, and I'm using MS graph API to get the data form the "Shifts App". Unfortunately, the 2021-04-18T00:00:00Z is completely different timezone and is very new to me. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? To me, this looks like a pretty standard  date string according to ISO 8601 with zero offset

Comment: I saw someone told to use moment.js? But I just wanna know if there is like, a OOTB function in javascript to convert iso to utc, so far I can't find any

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript help?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012854/change-iso-date-string-to-date-object-javascript

Comment: If that does not help, please edit your question to contain all code you've used to resolve the problem on your own

Comment: Thank you. It helps, although I go for a different approach. I used the toLocaleTimeString() and toUTCString()

Comment: Glad that the above helped. Thanks for confirming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Nico Haase comments

Use toLocaleTimeString() and toUTCString() methods and follow this for more help

[Change ISO Date String to Date Object - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012854/change-iso-date-string-to-date-object-javascript)